# QT QImage pixel manipulation

Tags: image, qt4, getpixel

I am building a QT GUI application and use QImage for opening images.
My problem is that I can't figure out how to use QImage's bit() and scanline()
methods to get access at per pixel level.

I've seen this post [Qt QImage pixel manipulation problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857962/qt-qimage-pixel-manipulation-problems)
but this is only for the first pixel of each row. Is this correct or I got it all wrong?

thanks in advance

Comment: oopps !! sorry!
after posting the question I found it at QT forums http://qt.nokia.com/doc/qq/qq17-imageio.html

and the answer is: 

 for (quint32 y = 0; y < h; ++y) {
            QRgb *scanLine = (QRgb *)img.scanLine(y);
   for (quint32 x = 0; x < w; ++x){
                pix = qBlue(scanLine[x]);
  }
        }

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [`scanlines`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#scanLine) correspond to the the height of image, the columns correspond to the width of the image.

According to the docs, the prototype looks like `uchar* QImage::scanline(int i)`, or a similar `const` version.

But, as a commenter pointed out, because the data is dependent on the machine architecture and image, you should **NOT** use the `uchar *` directly. Instead, use something like the following:

```
QRgb *rowData = (QRgb*)img.scanLine(row);
QRgb pixelData = rowData[col];
int red = qRed(pixelData);
```

Comment: -1: Attention! As this answer appears in Google-search even before the official Qt-API docu, I thought a word of warning is appropriate.  You CAN'T use [row][col] to access pixel data, as [col] would select an uchar and the pixel data is very depending on the bit-per-pixel format. Please see the warning in official docu "You cannot use the uchar* pointer directly, because the pixel format depends on the byte order on the underlying platform. Use qRed(), qGreen(), qBlue(), and qAlpha() to access the pixels." http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#scanLine

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect the correct way to access it.

Answer (score 13):

It may not be immediately obvious from Kaleb's post, but the following works for setting a pixel on a Format_RGB32 image.

```
// Get the line we want
QRgb *line = (QRgb *)image->scanLine(row_index);

// Go to the pixel we want
line += col_index;

// Actually set the pixel
*line = qRgb(qRed(color), qGreen(color), qBlue(color));
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer did not work for me. It looks like, the data is not 32bit aligned on my system.
To get the correct data, on my system i had to do this:

```
for(uint32_t Y = 0; Y < mHeight; ++Y)
{
    uint8_t* pPixel = Image.scanLine(Y);

    for(uint32_t X = 0; X < mWidth; ++X)
    {
      const int Blue = *pPixel++;
      const int Green = *pPixel++;
      const int Red = *pPixel++;

      uint8_t GrayscalePixel = (0.21f * Red) + (0.72f * Green) + (0.07 * Blue);
    }
}
```

Comment: The alignment depends of the pixel format! You have RGB888 unaligned pixel format here :) Always convert the rource image to format you want to work with, e.g. RGBA32 or ARGB32 or the like