# Store all QImage's pixels with scanLine() method in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, pointers, pixel

I am trying to modify an image using **Qt** with the [`scanLine()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qimage.html#scanLine) method. This methods return a pointer to the data of a given row. I founded how to read rows [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095039/qt-qimage-pixel-manipulation). Right now, I am able to read the value of all pixels like this:

```
QRgb ** pixels;

pixels = (QRgb **) (malloc(sizeof (QRgb*) * img->width() * img->height()));

#pragma omp parallel for
for (int y = 0; y < img->height(); ++y) {
    pixels[y] = (QRgb*) img->scanLine(y);
}

for (int x = 0; x < img->width(); ++x) {
    for (int y = 0; y < img->height(); ++y) {
        int color =  qRed(pixels[y][x]);
        std::cout << "Pixel at " << x << ", " << y << " is " << color << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Then, I process each pixel and try to add those in a new `QRgb **` variable, but this is where the program fails while executing.

```
QRgb ** finalPixels;

finalPixels = (QRgb **) (malloc(sizeof (QRgb*) * img->width() * img->height()));

    for (int x = 0; x < img->width(); ++x) {
        for (int y = 0; y < img->height(); ++y) {

            // Process pixels[y][x]


            QColor final(/* some new value */);
            QRgb finalrgb = final.rgb();

            finalPixels[y][x] = finalrgb; // What I realy want to do - Make the program fail
            finalPixels[y][x] = &finalrgb; // Don't build : invalid conversion from ‘QRgb* {aka unsigned int*}’ to ‘QRgb {aka unsigned int}’
            finalPixels[y][x] = pixels[y][x]; // Make the program fail


        }
    }
```

I don't understand why I can't change the reference of `finalPixels[y][x]` to a new reference. Is the type of the variable incorrect ? Or this is not how to do ? I readed some stuff about 2 dimensional arrays and pointers but still I can't figure out what is the problem here.

**EDIT**

@rames answered to this question by proposing to use `pixel()` and `setPixel()` methods. These methods are much easier to use, but this is not what I'm looking for. My first implementation was using these methods but as the [`setPixel()` method's documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qimage.html#setPixel) says:

> Warning: This function is expensive due to the call of the internal
>   `detach()` function called within; if performance is a concern, we
>   recommend the use of `scanLine()` to access pixel data directly.

And since my goal is to apply filters to an image like blur, edge detection, I need performance, so this is why I'm trying to use `scanLine()`.

---

I tried to change my variable type. And then simply change the pixels' color like this:

```
QRgb * pixels[img->height()];


#pragma omp parallel 
for (int y = 0; y < img->height(); ++y)
   pixels[y] = (QRgb*) img->scanLine();
}

for (int x = 0; x < img->width(); ++x) {
  for (int y = 0; y < img->height(); ++y) {
      QColor c(0,0,0);
      QRgb cr = c.rgb();
      pixels[y][x] = cr;
  }
}
```

But even this is failing when the program runs `pixels[y][x] = cr;` and I don't understand why. The output of QtCreator is `he program has unexpectedly finished.`.

---

Ok so I know how to modify the pixels of an image with the `scanLine()` method thanks to @user3528438 and @Rames. But still I can't find a way to get all the pixels in a variable. My goal is to have a temp variable, this way, I can compute a modification on the image with original pixels. Here is the last thing I tried:

```
QRgb * pixelsCopy[img->height()][img->width()];
QRgb * pColor;

for (int y = 0; y < img->height(); ++y) {
    for (int x = 0; x < img->width(); ++x) {
        pColor = new QRgb( (QRgb)img->scanLine(y)[x] );

        pixelsCopy[y][x] = pColor;
    }
}

for (int x = 0; x < img->width(); ++x) {
    for (int y = 0; y < img->height(); ++y) {
        int color =  qRed(*pixelsCopy[y][x]); // Return 0
        std::cout << "Pixel at " << x << ", " << y << " is " << color << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This compile and run well, but all values are 0.. If I compare to the original pixels, this is not the case. Can you explain to me why my values are not the original onces and are all set to 0 in my `*pixelsCopy` variable ? And also, isn't is too heavy to call `scanLine()` method for each pixel ? I also tried to change `*pixelsCopy` to `pixelsCopy`, but I still get 0 values..

**EDIT 2**

Thanks to @user3528438 and @Rames, I finally found a way to **copy** pixels into a new variable, but I am getting weird results. I wrote a code that copy the pixels and reapply those to the image and I am not getting the same image.

```
QRgb pixelsCopy[img->height()][img->width()];

for (int y = 0; y < img->height(); ++y) {
    QRgb * line = reinterpret_cast<QRgb *>(img->scanLine(y));
    for (int x = 0; x < img->width(); ++x) {
        pixelsCopy[y][x] = line[x];
    }
}

for (int x = 0; x < img->width(); ++x) {
    for (int y = 0; y < img->height(); ++y) {
        int r = qRed(pixelsCopy[y][x]);
        QColor final(r, r, r);
        img->scanLine(y)[x] = final.rgb();

    }
}
```

And this is the before and after:
[image]

It looks like a coordinate mistake but I checked multiple times and saw nothing.. If you have a **faster** and/or **cleaner** way to copy the original pixels, It will be nice to advice me !

Comment: `the program fails` is not much to work with.  How can you tell that it has failed?

Comment: the way you allocate the memory is horribly wrong. and the decision to use `**` is questionable, too. i suggest not to use `**` in this case unless there are very compelling reasons.

Comment: @DaleWilson When I run the application with QtCreator, this is the only output that I get. I tested and noticed that it cames from here.

Comment: @user3528438 Then what should I use ? `QRgb pixels[width][height];` ? But if I do this, do I have to allocate memory ?

Comment: It depends on your usage, or what's the scope/lifetime you want it to have.

Comment: @user3528438 I don't know, what is the best for a use in a method ? In the future, I would set this variable as an attribute of a class which inherit from QImage, like this, I don't have to do the work each time I want to work on the pixels.

Comment: You should use the pointer returned from `scanLine` or `bits` directly instead of creating a new array or allocating new memory. Still, manipulating pixels this way, and inheriting from QImage, are both questionable designs. Consider `QPainter`? Your second solution seems it should work, except that converting the pointer to `QRGB*` does not look right. Also the openmp does not seem necessary, nor safe.

Comment: @user3528438 If I use `scanLine` directly, wouldn't it be too heavy to call the method for each pixel ? (Like this `QRgb color = img->scanLine(y)[x]`). And why the conversion is does not look right in the second solution ? I though that cast was ok since I am able to read the colors. I also removed openmp. Thanks !

Comment: I tested `img->scanLine(y)[x] = final.rgb();` and it works perfectly, but I am afraid that it will be too slow. Moreover, I have to make some filter that need to create a temp variable of all pixels, so I will still be stuck with that problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since my question was a bit too wide, I created [a topic on the Qt Forum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/73504/qimage-read-pixels-and-copy-them-with-scanline-method) and **[Chris Kawa](https://forum.qt.io/user/chris-kawa)** answered precisely to my problem.

**Copy the pixels into another variable**

```
int size = img->height() * img->width();
QRgb* data = new QRgb[size]; //don't forget to delete it somewhere
memmove(data, img.bits(), img.height() * img.width() * sizeof(QRgb));
// We don't need to copy each pixel, that's slow
```

**Process each pixel**

We can read each pixel by incrementing x and y.

```
for (int y = 0; y < img->height(); ++y) {
   for (int x = 0; x < img->width(); ++x) {
```

But this is going to be slow, it will be much faster to use pointers.

```
QRgb* ptr = data;
QRgb* end = ptr + img.width() * img.height();
for (; ptr < end; ++ptr)
    *ptr = qRgb(qRed(*ptr), qRed(*ptr), qRed(*ptr));
```

**STD Style : Copy the pixels into another variable**

```
//copy
std::vector<QRgb> pixels;
pixels.resize(img.height() * img.width());
memmove(pixels.data(), img.bits(), img.height() * img.width() * sizeof(QRgb));
```

**STD Style : Process each pixel**

```
std::for_each(pixels.begin(), pixels.end(), [](QRgb& c) { c = qRgb(qRed(c), qRed(c), qRed(c)); });
```

In c++17 you'll even be able to parallelize and vertorize it easily like this:

```
std::for_each(std::execution::parallel_unsequenced_policy, 
              pixels.begin(), pixels.end(), [](QRgb& c) { c = qRgb(qRed(c), qRed(c), qRed(c)); });
```

---

Thank Chris Kawa for the help, all the code above was given by him on the topic I created on the Qt Forum.

Answer (score 2):

Do **not** use an array. The [`QImage`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html) class is designed for pixel manipulation and you really should use this one. Assuming that `img` variable is of type `QImage *`:

```
QImage finalImage(*img);
for (int y = 0; y < finalImage.height(); ++y) {
    QRgb *line = reinterpret_cast<QRgb*>(finalImage.scanLine(y));
    for (int x = 0; x < finalImage.width(); ++x) {
        QRgb pixelRgb = line[x];
        // Process pixelRgb

        QColor final(/* some new value */);
        line[x] = final.rgb();
    }
}
```

Comment: no this is what I used before and it was working but this is too **heavy and slow**. As said in [`setPixel` documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qimage.html#setPixel): `This function is expensive due to the call of the internal detach() function called within; if performance is a concern, we recommend the use of scanLine() to access pixel data directly.`

Comment: And there is no `setPixelColor` method

Comment: @KevinM `setPixelColor` was introduced in Qt 5.6. You haven't explicitly mentioned that you are using Qt 4.8. As far as performance is concerned I will try to show you the quicker version in next edit.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I tried your code and it doesn't compile for me. I get this error : `error: invalid static_cast from type ‘uchar* {aka unsigned char*}’ to type ‘QRgb* {aka unsigned int*}’` Do you know why ?

Comment: @KevinM Updated, changed type of cast. If this line still doesn't compile (though it really should), try to change it to `QRgb *line = (QRgb*)(finalImage.scanLine(y));`

Comment: This cast doesn't work neither. I'm looking for a way to store all scanLine in one variable, and if possible, copy the values to keep an original copy of the pixels

Comment: @KevinM The cast is correct. What do you mean by doesn't work? And in my code snippet you keep original image under `img` variable.