# Setting pixel color of 8-bit grayscale image using pointer

Tags: c++, qt, qimage

I have this code:

```
QImage grayImage = image.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_Grayscale8);
int size = grayImage.width() * grayImage.height();
QRgb *data = new QRgb[size];
memmove(data, grayImage.constBits(), size * sizeof(QRgb));

QRgb *ptr = data;
QRgb *end = ptr + size;
for (; ptr < end; ++ptr) {
    int gray = qGray(*ptr);
}

delete[] data;
```

It is based on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40740985/8257882

How can I set the color of a pixel using that pointer?

In addition, using qGray() and loading a "bigger" image seem to crash this.

This works:

```
int width = image.width();
int height = image.height();
for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
        image.setPixel(x, y, qRgba(0, 0, 0, 255));
    }
}
```

But it is slow when compared to explicitly manipulating the image data.

**Edit**

Ok, I have this code now:

```
for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
    uchar *line = grayImage.scanLine(y);
    for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
        int gray = qGray(line[x]);
        *(line + x) = uchar(gray);
        qInfo() << gray;
    }
}
```

And it seems to work. However, when I use an image that has only black and white colors and print the gray value, black color gives me 0 and white gives 39. How can I get the gray value in a range of 0-255?

Comment: You should not be using `qGray`. It should be `uchar gray = line[x]`. `line[x]` is already the gray value. If you use `gray = qGray(line[x])`, you are applying this formula: `(R * 11 + G * 16 + B * 5)/32`. In your case, B is the least significant byte (in `QRgb`) and 255*5/32=39.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you are copying too much data in this line:

```
memmove(data, grayImage.constBits(), size * sizeof(QRgb));
```

The size ob Qrgb is 4 bytes, but according to the documentation, the size of a Format_Grayscale8 pixel is only 8 bits or 1 byte. If you remove `sizeof(QRgb)` you should be copying the correct amount of bytes, assuming all the lines in the bitmap are consecutive (which, according to the documentation, they are not -- they are aligned to at minimum 32-bits, so you would have to account for that in `size`). The array `data` should not be of type `Qrgb[size]` but `ucahr[size]`. You can then modify `data` as you like.  Finally, you will probably have to create a new QImage with one of the constructors that accept image bits as `uchar` and assign the new image to the old image:

```
auto newImage = QImage( data, image.width(), image.height(), QImage::Format_Grayscale8, ...);
grayImage = std::move( newImage );
```

But instead of copying image data, you could probably just modify `grayImage` directly by accessing its data through `bits()`, or even better, through `scanLine()`, maybe something like this:

```
int line, column;
auto pLine = grayImage.scanLine(line);
*(pLine + column) = uchar(grayValue);
```

**EDIT**:

According to scanLine documentation, the image is at least 32-bit aligned. So if your 8-bit grayScale image is 3 pixels wide, a new scan line will start every 4 bytes. If you have a 3x3 image, the total size of the memory required to hold the image pixels will be 12. The following code shows the required memory size:

```
int main() {
   auto image = QImage(3, 3, QImage::Format_Grayscale8);
   std::cout << image.bytesPerLine() * image.height() << "\n";
   return 0;
}
```

The `fill` method (setting all gray values to 0xC0) could be implemented like this:

```
   auto image = QImage(3, 3, QImage::Format_Grayscale8);
   uchar gray = 0xc0;
   for ( int i = 0; i < image.height(); ++i ) {
      auto pLine = image.scanLine( i );
      for ( int j = 0; j < image.width(); ++j )
         *pLine++ = gray;
   }
```

Comment: "assuming all the lines in the bitmap are consecutive (which, according to the documentation, they are not -- they are aligned to at minimum 32-bits". But shouldn't they be consecutive now when every pixel is 8 bits? Especially, when we change the data to uchar type. If I understand correctly, I would have to multiply the size by 4 if every pixel was 32 bits to align the data properly.

Comment: Also this: "But, as a commenter pointed out, because the data is dependent on the machine architecture and image, you should NOT use the uchar * directly." https://stackoverflow.com/a/2095127/8257882

Comment: The answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/2095127/8257882 does not apply - it works only for RGBA (32-bit) images, but you have an 8-bit image. `uchar` is 8-bit, so no conversion is needed.

Comment: Don't you mean the size of a 3x3 image is 9 bytes instead of 12 bytes if it's an 8-bit image?

Comment: 32-bit (4-byte) alignment means that the difference in the address of two consecutive scan lines is dividable by 4. That means, that the amount of memory needed for a single line is dividable by 4. If your image has 3 columns, it needs 3 bytes for the pixels and one extra byte for alignment, so 4 bytes. And 3x4 is 12.

Comment: Ok, thanks for all the help! I really learned a lot here.